# $\chi^2$ distribution Stoch. increasing in non-centrality parameter

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

i.e for fixed $\nu>0$ if we have $\gamma_2 > \gamma_1>0$ then $\chi^{2}_{\nu}(\gamma_2)\succeq\chi^2_{\nu}(\gamma_1)$ where '$\succeq$' denotes *stochastically larger*.

The convention that I follow: "if $X \sim N(\theta,1)$ then $X^2 \sim \chi^2_1(\frac{\theta^2}{2})$

**My Attempt**: For $\nu=1$, first define $X \sim N(\theta,1)$ where $\theta>0$. Then
$$P(X^2>t^2)=2-\Phi(t-\theta)-\Phi(t+\theta)=f(\theta) \hspace{10pt} (\text{say})$$
Then $f(\theta)$ is an increasing fnction in $\theta$.

For $\nu=$integer greater that $1$ the proof follows from the above and induction using the following **Lemma/Theorem**

"$X\succeq Y$ $\iff$ $\exists$ a single probability space on which are defined $\tilde{X},\tilde{Y}$ such that $\tilde{X} \sim F_{X}$, $\tilde{Y} \sim F_{Y}$ and $P(X\geq Y)=1$"

i.e. on some probability space $X \sim \chi^2_1(\gamma_2)$, $Y \sim \chi^2_1(\gamma_1)$ such that $X\geq Y$ w.p. $1$. Then adding both side (independent of $X$ and $Y$) $W \sim \chi^2_{\nu-1}(0)$ the desired result follows.

**My Questions**

(1) The above proof does not work when $\nu$ is not an integer (viewing $\chi^2_{\nu}$ distribution as $Gamma(2,\frac{\nu}{2})$). So is there any proof which takes care of that problem?

(2) I came across the **Lemma/Theorem** (which I stated) in my old probability notes but I do not have any reference of it which I am eagerly waiting for. Any kind of help/hint/enlightenment is what I am looking for and shall certainly appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding (2). The lemma refers to the notion of coupling. The proof is as follows:

$(\Leftarrow)$ Trivial. If $P\{\bar X\ge \bar Y\}=1$ then $F_X(x)\le F_Y(x)$ for all $x$-s.

$(\Rightarrow)$ $X\succeq Y$. Consider the following  prob. space $([0,1],\mathcal{B}[0,1],\mu)$ and let $\bar X(\omega)=F_X^{-1}(\omega)$, $\bar Y(\omega)=F_Y^{-1}(\omega)$. $\bar X$ is a copy of $X$ because

$$P\{\bar X\le x\}=\mu\{\omega:F_X^{-1}(\omega)\le x\}=\mu\{\omega:\omega\le F_X(x)\}=F_X(x)$$

Similarly $\bar Y$ is a copy of $Y$. Stochastic dominance implies that for all $\omega\in [0,1]$

$$\bar X(\omega)=F_X^{-1}(\omega)\ge F_Y^{-1}(\omega)=\bar Y(\omega)$$